# Jquery setInterval not working, only first div id working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, setinterval

I am trying to build live comment system for my website, live  comments loading only first div id I don't know Whats wrong with my code

**html code**

```
            <div id="load_comc_1">
            <div id="load_comc_2">
            <div id="load_comc_3">



    <input type="hidden" id="clientcom" value="<?php echo $d['qid']; ?>">


      //loadcomments here

        </div>
```

**jquery code**

```
     $( document ).ready(function() {

    var i=$("#clientcom").attr("value");

    setInterval(function(){
    $("#load_comc_" + i).load("get_timeline_records.php #load_comc_" + i);

     },1000);

     });
```

I want to load comments within live please help me thank  in advance

Comment: Not really sure what your code is supposed to be doing, but how would you expect `#clientcom` value to ever change?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak I think  that not a problem

Comment: What issue do you face?Plz check in browser network tab if you are able to receive response from server

Comment: You need to input different value for every second, which will match with your div id pattern

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal set interval works only for the first div id  But i need multiple  like  I mentioned above

Comment: They're only loading for the first div because `i` doesn't ever change.

Comment: @MadhuReddyVadlakonda just put the console.log("i value", i); in your setInterval function and observe the value at every second

Comment: yes I have tried no results

Comment: @freedomn-m please give me any solution

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

**html code**

```
        <div id="load_comc_1" class="testdIV">
        <div id="load_comc_2" class="testdIV">
        <div id="load_comc_3" class="testdIV">
        <input type="hidden" id="clientcom" value="<?php echo $d['qid']; ?>">
      //loadcomments here
       </div>
```

**jquery code**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
var i=0;
var totalLenght = $("#clientcom").length    
setInterval(function(){
i=totalLenght - i
$("#load_comc_" + i).load("get_timeline_records.php #load_comc_" + i);

 },1000);
 });
```

Comment: I have edit my answer please check @MadhuReddyVadlakonda